# Transparent theme puts items to center

Tags: android

I want to make an activity which is mainly transparent except for a gridview and a textview, so my style is:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

and my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView ... android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

<GridView ...
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 />
```

However textview and gridview are in the exact center, ignoring my bottom layout gravity...

Comment: Can I ask what the larger goal is?  Why do yo need a whole `Activity` that is just a `TextView`?

Comment: that's not how it works. linear layout is a stack of items from top to bottom (in vertical mode)

Comment: TextView+Gridview! Anyway it's for a custom share intent selection and that is a box, so it should overlay current activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `LinearLayout` can not do this, use a `RelativeLayout` instead.  A `RelativeLayout` will give you access to the `centerInParent` attribute in it's children..

here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">  //<---- this here is the trick
        <TextView ... 
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        <GridView ...
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You might be able to get rid of that `LinearLayout`, and I would suggest messing around with this.  It depends on how you need the view to look.

Either way, a `RelativeLayout` and a `layout_centerInParent` should do what you want.

Comment: Solved without inner linear layout this way:                            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
    
    <GridView android:id="@+id/theGrid" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@id/theGrid"/>

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: AlignPartentBottom was the best option, and manually setting layout_heigth to 200dp ensures me that grid will not cover the entire parent on small screens!:)

Comment: yeah, RelativeLayouts are really powerful.  Not only can you align children to their parent, but you can also use `layout_toLeftOf` (and variations) to place children relative to each other.